# anyone have example python code that sends mail using sendmail and subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, sendmail

I'm kind of confused about how `subprocess.Popen` works. If anyone has example code that sends email using the subprocess module and sendmail that'd be great.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why sendmail instead of Python's smtplib?

Comment: actually right now i'm using smtplib, but for some reason the To: address doesn't show up in emails.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to ask (via posting the code in question) why the To: address doesn't show up in the emails?

Comment: @Joe, I provided an answering showing why you probably aren't getting the To address to show up in the headers.  If that works for you, please accept it but *first* edit your question to summarize this series of comments and make it clear the accepted answer doesn't address the question as described in its title...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but given your response to a comment by "DNS", it might solve your problem.

When sending SMTP mail, you need to understand that the "from" and "to" addresses that you pass to the smtplib.sendmail() routine as arguments are *not* the same thing as what you see in the From: and To: headers in the message when it's received.  Those arguments become parameters given to the receiving SMTP mailer, with the "MAIL FROM" and "RCPT TO" commands.  This is commonly referred to as the "envelope" of the mail, and the values usually show up in the Received: header lines.

To specify the headers you want, you have to supply them yourself before the body of the message.  The [smtplib example](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example) shows how that's done, in that case with a tuple called "msg" that they prepend to the message body.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first gotchas I encountered with `subprocess` was the fact that it doesn't take full shell string commands by default.

If you want to do the equivalent of a shell command like:

```
os.system("echo hello world")
```

you need to use the `shell=True` option:

```
subprocess.Popen("echo hello world", shell=True)
```

Comment: It's not really a gotcha: well documented. It's also one of the reasons subprocess rocks. :)